# Error connecting to database ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#

I keep getting this error:
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

This line of code:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("PayrollSystem_DBConnectionString"))
```

I think I need sql statements instead of Ole, I'm not sure.

Here is my form html code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PayrollSystem_DBConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PayrollSystem_DBConnectionString.ProviderName %>"
```

Here is my frmManageUsers code:

```
public partial class frmManageUsers : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void btnAddUser_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                //string userName, userPassword;



        if (txtUserName.Text == "" || txtUserName.Text == null)
        {
            lblError.Text = ("User Name may not be empty");
            lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            return;
        }
       // else

           // userName = (txtUserName.Text);


        if (txtPassword.Text == "" || txtPassword.Text == null)
        {
            lblError.Text = ("Password may not be empty");
            lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            return;
        }
        //else
           // userPassword = (txtPassword.Text);

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("PayrollSystem_DBConnectionString"))
            {
                string insert = "Insert INTO tblUserLogin (UserName, UserPassword, SecurityLevel) Values (@UserName, @UserPassword, @SecurityLevel)";
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(insert, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", txtUserName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserPassword", txtPassword.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@SecurityLevel", drpdwnlstSecurityLevel.SelectedValue);  
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();      
            }

        Session["UserName"] = txtUserName.Text;
        Session["Password"] = txtPassword.Text;
        Session["SecurityLevel"] = drpdwnlstSecurityLevel.SelectedValue;
        Server.Transfer("frmManageUsers.aspx");

        //Server.Transfer("grdUserLogin"); 

    }
    protected void drpdwnlstSecurityLevel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: what's your connection string look like?

Comment: @jim: <add name="PayrollSystem_DBConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\LOCATION HERE\PayrollSystem_DB.mdb"

Comment: is this a REAL payroll system for a REAL place or is this for academia?

Answer (score 1):

OleDbConnection takes the actual connection string, not the NAME of the connection string.  You have to get the connection string from the Configuration using `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PayrollSystem_DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString` and pass that to OleDbConnection

Comment: @Mike - Exactly as I said, you pass it to your OleDbConnection.  I'm not sure how I could say it any clearer.

Comment: using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PayrollSystem_DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString))

Comment: @Mystere Man:  I don't understand this stuff.  It has taken me a long time just to get where I am.  So I'm assuming this line goes before OleDbConnection right?  I did it like that and the whole line is an error.  Visual Studio 3.5 isn't recognizing "ConfigurationManager".

Comment: @mike are you doing this for real life? or is a school project?

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you're using a 64-bit system, you need to change the connection string to use the new provider, Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0

You can download it here:

- [Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0 .NET Database Provider](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en)